# Append/replace string from one file with information from another

Tags: python, replace, append, text-files

My Python skills are rusty and I've looked on StackOverflow and online but what I'd like to do is more complex than most and doesn't include a third file.

Basically, I have two files with some identical fields (title) and common but not identical (link). I want to take the ISBN (a unique number) from the link in one file and append/replace it in the link field in the other file. At first I tried checking against the title then updating that link field but that seemed too complicated. Each title has a link field and an ISBN.

This current code grabs the ISBN from the first file, I'm just stuck on how to append it to the link field in the other file. Thanks!

```
#This code compares two .txt files, matches on titles, and copies ISBN into the link
title = "title: "
link = "856"
isbn = ""
with open("test-original.txt", "r") as file, open("test-change.txt", "a") as change:
    for line in file:
        if link in line:
            isbn = line.strip("856 http://www.example.com/")
            print change.write(line.replace("com/", "com/" + isbn))
    #for line in change:
        #if title in line:
            #print line.strip("title: ")
```

Comment: What is the `print` intended to do? The `change.write` method will return the number of characters written. Did you want to do something with that?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "append/replace"? Are you trying to append the modified line to the end of `test-change.txt`, even if there's already a corresponding line there, or are you trying to modify any corresponding line in-place? Your existing code seems like it should already be doing the former just fine. If you want the latter… well, first you have to define what you mean by "the corresponding line", and then you'll run into the problem that you can't replace lines in-place in a text file anyway, you have to write out a new file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two things you could mean here. You say you want to "append/replace" the modified line from the first file to the second file.

If you mean "append", you're already doing exactly that.

If you mean "replace", then you have to explain what you're trying to replace. I'm going to assume, for simplicity, that the lines are in lock-step order: line 20 of `test-original` matches up with line 20 of `test-change`, so it's line 20 of `test-change` that you want to replace. (If the "corresponding line" that you wanted to replace is something different, then you may have to read the file into memory, search it, use `linecache`, etc.; without knowing what exactly you intend by "corresponding", I have no idea how to write it…)

Also, you can't replace a line in a text-file in-place. A text file is just a stream of characters; if you overwrite a 60-character line with an 80-character line, you've just overwritten the first 20 characters of the next line.

So, what you want to do is write a *new* file—normally, you write a temporary file, then move it on top of the original once you've finished. So:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporary("w", dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
    with open("test-original.txt", "r") as file, open("test-change.txt", "r") as change:
        for origline, changeline in zip(file, change):
            if link in origline:
                isbn = origline.strip("856 http://www.example.com/")
                tmp.write(origline.replace("com/", "com/" + isbn))
            else:
                tmp.write(changeline)
os.replace(tmp.name, "test-change.txt")
```

---

Note that `os.replace` requires Python 3.3, and your code looks like Python 2.x. Unfortunately, replacing a file in a safe and atomic way that works even on Windows is very painful (which is exactly why `os.replace` was added). If you're not worried about atomicity, instead of `os.replace`, do this:

```
os.remove("test-change.txt")
os.rename(tmp.name, "test-change.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to do. However, now the isbn gets pasted twice in the new file rather than once at the end of the link. What is causing this?

Comment: The problem was in the if statement--so I changed it to tmp.write(changeline.replace("com/", "com/" + isbn)) and it works perfectly. Thanks!